# Inconsistant NSZombie allocation log

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, instruments, nszombie

I'm working on old code now imported into Xcode 7.

My problem is I have a random crash when changing a master/detail view controller that is pretty basic.

The crash happens in main() so, not really helpful, but it's a message sent to an released object.

I tried running in Instruments "NSZombie", but when I get the crash, the trace isn't really consistant. It indicates 4 times the same line in the code for malloc / autorelease / retain / release, and that code is not even doing an allocation:

```
SSHTunnel *tunnel = [ tunnels objectAtIndex: rowIndex ];
```

That's the line pointed by Instruments, 4 times.

The crash itself is on a message sent to an unallocated instance of NSException.

The project is an old project, and I think *maybe* a compiler setting is missing or misconfigured.

For example, if I set "development" settings in that scheme, I get the error in the next bloc, always, now I'm using Development build in that scheme it points to another location but still doesn't make sense.

What should I check now?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was actually happening in that location, but in a really weird may. I was accessing an index out of bounds in NSArray, that's the exception I expected to have but for some reason it didn't... Oh well, one of those days...